# Why is this Xamarin.Forms autowire binding connecting my Command but not my Entry?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage
...
    x:Class="MyProj.LoginPageView"
    local:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
...cut for brevity...
        <Entry MinimumWidthRequest="60"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Entry Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  VerticalOptions="Center"  Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Button Text="Login" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
        <Button Text="Register" Command="{Binding RegisterCommand}"/>
```

Attached using autowiring to this viewmodel:

```cs
public class LoginPageViewModel: BindableObject
    {
        public ICommand LoginCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand RegisterCommand { get; set; }

        private string username;
        private string password;

        public string Username { get { return username; } set { username = value; OnPropertyChanged("Username"); } }
        public string Password { get { return password; } set { password = value; OnPropertyChanged("Password"); } }

        public LoginPageViewModel()
        {
            LoginCommand = new Command(() =>
              Login());
            RegisterCommand = new Command(() =>
            Register());
        }

        private void Login()
        {

        }

        private void Register()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("sdfsd");
        }
    }
```

The command bindings are working fine and the Register and Login methods get called when I click the button. In the autowiring the binding context of the view is set to the viewmodel as follows:

```cs
        static ViewModelLocator()
        {

            _container = new TinyIoCContainer();

            //register viewmodels
            _container.Register<LoginPageViewModel>();
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty AutoWireViewModelProperty =
    BindableProperty.CreateAttached("AutoWireViewModel", typeof(bool), typeof(ViewModelLocator), default(bool), propertyChanged: OnAutoWireViewModelChanged);

        public static bool GetAutoWireViewModel(BindableObject bindable)
        {
            return (bool)bindable.GetValue(ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModelProperty);
        }

        public static void SetAutoWireViewModel(BindableObject bindable, bool value)
        {
            bindable.SetValue(ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModelProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnAutoWireViewModelChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var view = bindable as Element;
            if (view == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var viewType = view.GetType();
            var viewName = viewType.FullName.Replace(".Views.", ".ViewModels.");
            var viewAssemblyName = viewType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName;
            var viewModelName = string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}Model, {1}", viewName, viewAssemblyName);

            var viewModelType = Type.GetType(viewModelName);
            if (viewModelType == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            var viewModel = _container.Resolve(viewModelType);
            view.BindingContext = viewModel;
        }
```

When I click register in debug mode the register method gets called which means the command binding has been connected but the value I put in the Entry fields for username and password aren't connected to the corresponding properties on the VM and the properties just have null values.

Comment: You need to inherit your viewmodel from `INotifyPropertyChanged` instead of BindableObject, then register each property you have to PropertyChanged, take a look to the [official mvvm binding documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm) for Xamarin Forms.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is not a class, it's an interface and BinadableObject already implements it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: Set the binding Mode as `OneWayToSource` .

Comment: No difference, the Username/Password is still not set.

Comment: Could you share a sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: I can share it later today possibly. I found that the OnAutoWireViewModelChanged function is not being called so perhaps you can help me identify why that is? I've put in the definition of the attached property.

Comment: @FabriBertani I am aware of interface inheritance but I don't see how it will help me now. I also don't understand how you think implementing INotifyPropertyChanged directly instead of through BindableObject will help me implement the ViewModelLocator pattern. However, I went ahead and tried it anyway and got the same result.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I made a sample project and copied the relevant code over and it is inexplicably working in the fresh project. I don't really know why it's not working in the other one but at least I know now that it's not an issue with that part of the code.